# How to interrupting ALAnimatedSpeech

Tags: python-2.7, pepper

I'm developing behavior for Pepper as a service (.py) and want to stop the robot talking, i.e. stop audio and movement from ALAnimatedSpeech.say("some text string as speech").
However the [API](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alanimatedspeech-api.html) does not have a .stop() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ALAnimatedSpeech._stopAll(True)`

Comment: Note to those who are interested: To see all methods, including hidden ones, call:
qicli call ALAnimatedSpeech.getMethodList  | python -m json.tool

Comment: also try this easier command from the robot shell:
qicli info ALAnimatedSpeech --hidden